# Connecting to a remote database using Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have domain , database name, database user and password

I want to connect to my database remotely using visual studio 2010, How can I do this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to do it with connection string

Comment: No using the server explorer ..

Answer (score 2):

there are many different ways to do it depending on the database type you're using

if you are looking for a smarter way you can use Visual Studio Toolbox and add a data source.

https://web.archive.org/web/20121018072209/http://www.programminghelp.com/software/visual-studio-net/how-to-create-a-data-source-in-visual-studio-net/

Comment: the link you provided is broken. @vasa

Answer (score 0):

it easier to do it with connection string but in order to achive this when you want to open add new sql server connection either with server explorer or just by writing the connection string since server ui still creates the connection sttring you need to know

Data Source=SERVER  the ip adress of the server where sql server is istalled
Replace Integrated Security with User ID and Password if you are using
SQL Authentication.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/17/creating-a-database-connection-to-a-remote-sql-server-database-within-visual-web-developer.aspx